# Failed to minify the bundle. Error: static/js/main.1f26fd13.chunk.js from Terser

Tags: reactjs, npm, minify

Created a new react app and tried building a production version using the "npm run build" command and it is giving the following error :

"Failed to minify the bundle. Error: static/js/main.1f26fd13.chunk.js from Terser
TypeError: Cannot read property 'minify' of undefined
    at compiler.run. " .

Comment: try running `npm install`

Comment: The issue is with the latest version of "terser". I downgraded its version to "3.14.0" in the "package.json" file and did a "npm update" .It seems to work for me .Thanks .

Answer (score 2):

Try

`npm install terser@3.14.1 --save-dev`

[Github Discussion Link](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/6336)